# Buffer reader adding "[?1034h" as last line when executing Linux commands in Java

Tags: java, bufferedreader

I'm executing a linux command in java using processBuilder but it adds `[?1034h` as the last line.

It is printing all lines but after my expected last line, it adds another line with those characters.

My code:

```
 ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder();

        // -- Linux --

        // Run a shell command
        processBuilder.command("bash", "-c", "sudo /usr/sbin/ilorest load -f "+biossource);

    

        try {

            Process process = processBuilder.start();

             output = new StringBuilder();

            BufferedReader  reader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                output.append(line);
            }
             BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new 
                     InputStreamReader(process.getErrorStream()));
                     
                     System.out.println("Here is the standard error of the command (if any):\n");
                while ((line = stdError.readLine()) != null) {
                    output.append(line);
                    System.out.println(line);
                }
            int exitVal = process.waitFor();
            if (exitVal == 0) {
                System.out.println("Success!");
                System.out.println(output);
                System.exit(0);
            } else {
                //abnormal...
            }
```

I also wrote the output to file and even there it is showing the same.

Comment: Looks like an ANSI escape for the terminal.

Comment: so how to overcome that

Comment: I had to think of Ctrl-D + \n as Ctrl-D = end-of-file, and the bytes 4, 10 (depending on the endianess) could very well be 4*256+10 = 1034, a short 'h'.

Comment: One possible error cause would be encoding. You are using InputStreamReader without charset encoding. It will default to the platform encoding, which however seems correct. Maybe you should execute `sudo` without `bash`.

Comment: This problem has been reported by other folks using Python's `readline` module. I don't know enough about Python to know how to fix it. If this were my problem to solve, I'd filter the bogus text out of the response, perhaps using `string.replaceAll()`.